# How to align subtitles on top of the video in mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediaelement.js

Thanks in advance folks,

I wanted to align my subtitle on top of the video for 10 seconds in the beginning.

```
1
00:00:00.500 --> 00:00:05.000 line:15% 
Early on, the initial signs are more subtle word-finding difficulties,
```

I have used the line attribute of WEBVTT as shown above and it's working in normal HTML video but it's not working mejs, please offer remedies

Please find the below image, that's how it needs to be.[image: Subtitle on top]

[image: Subtitle on bottom]

Comment: As per my findings, I got to know that the **Mediaelement** player is not handling the **WEBVTT** positioning very much.